# Lower disk sizes in Azure with high IOPS

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

If one looks at the pricing tiers for disks in Azure storage (Premium SSDs one below as of today for the East US region), the higher the IOPS offered the higher the disk size.

One can choose a higher performance tier but use a lower disk size (although it won't make much sense probably, as you'd still be paying for the respective tier and corresponding size). But why isn't there an option to get a small disk (e.g. 32 GB) with a high number of IOPS?

In another words, why is there this forced correlation between disk size and IOPS?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why isn't there an option to get a small disk (e.g. 32 GB) with a high number of IOPS?

For most storage technologies IOPS and Size are linked, and premium storage offers *provisioned* IOPS.  Conceptually* a P4 is just 1/32nd of a P30, and you can't allow a P4 to use more than 1/32nd of the available IOPS without degrading the performance of the other small disks that share the storage.

*The actual implementation is probably more complex.

Comment: I get this scenario whereby a big disk is split into multiple "shares" and each is used by each client. You can't allow one client to eat up more of its share of IOPS in this case, as the others are hurt. But considering 2 separate physical disks, is the increase in IOPS for a larger-sized model the result of technical improvements (as bigger and better drives tend to appear in time) or is there some inherent characteristic that will actually make a larger drive perform better than its smaller sibling from the standpoint of IOPS?

Comment: The "disks" that you provision in the Azure Portal bear little-to-no resemblance to the storage devices that are actually used to store your data.  It's the underlying physical devices that tend to have a linear correlation between space and IOPS.  But features like "bursting" indicate that the correlation doesn't _have_ to be super strict, and may evolve over time.

Comment: But for those underlying physical devices, what would trigger one that has twice the capacity of another to have a proportional increase in IOPS, assuming the technology used in building the 2 disks identical? (I realize that we're straying away from Azure and the original question)

Comment: Being built from arrays of small flash chips or even spinning disks has this effect.